# Property of Conical Hull

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space and $C$ be a nonempty convex subset of $H$. The *conical hull* of $C$ is defined by 
$$ \operatorname{cone}{C} := \bigcup_{\lambda >0}{\lambda C}.
$$

(it is a cone in the sense that if $x \in \operatorname{cone}{C}$ and $\lambda >0$ then $\lambda x \in \operatorname{cone}{C}$).

When trying to prove Proposition 6.16 of the book "Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces" written by Professors Heinz Bauschke and Patrick Combettes, I think that the following property of conical hull maybe true:

Let $C$ be a nonempty convex subset of $H$. Assume that $\mathrm{int}{C}\neq \varnothing$ and $0 \in C$. If $k>0$, then there exists $m>0$ such that 
$$ B(0,k) \cap \operatorname{cone}{C} \subset mC.
$$

I guess this property by drawing some pictures of conical hull. Unfortunately, I am struggling to prove it.

Here is my question: Is the above property correct? If so, could you please give me some clues?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: 1. I do not see where your question involves the conic hull. 2. What is $B(0,k)$? 3. In any case, you can choose $m = 1$.

Comment: @gerw Thank you very much for your comment. I have edited my question. Indeed it should be $B(0,k) \cap \operatorname{cone}{C}$ instead of $B(0,k)\cap C$, where $B(0,k) = \left\{ x \in H : \Vert x \Vert \leq k \right\}$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is even fails in dimension $2$. Just try $C = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid (x-1)^2 + y^2 \le 2 \}$.